How to exclude framework for simulator - xCode
I have framework that run only on real device, when I run on simulator I have the following errors:

Build failed because xxxxSDK.swiftmodule is not built for arm64
Could not find module 'xxxxSDK' for target 'arm64-apple-ios-simulator'; found: arm64-apple-io

I tried to exclude SDK from simulator but without luck, what configuration I need to add to run on simulator

Should you employ a third-party framework in the form of 'framework', you may utilize macros to exclude the inclusion of header files and method invocations.
#if targetEnvironment(simulator)  
    // 代码仅在模拟器中编译和执行  
    print("Running on Simulator")  
#else  
    // 代码仅在真机中编译和执行  
    print("Running on Device")  
#endif  

If you can usr an 'xcframework', you have the option to craft and integrate a framework emulating the simulator platform. This requires only the header files and a trivial implementation of the corresponding methods.
xcodbuild  -create-xcframework ....
